# SwiftUI sending a variable to transition

Tags: swiftui

I am displaying an image and would like to control the transition with a variable. My code looks like this;

```
Image(uiImage: slideStore.images[activeImageIndex])
    .resizable()
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .scaledToFill()
    .transition(.move(edge: .top))
    .animation(.default)
```

How do I use a variable to switch between .top and .bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a @State for this:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var update: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {

        Image(uiImage: slideStore.images[activeImageIndex])
            .resizable()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .scaledToFill()
            .transition(.move(edge: update ? .top : .bottom ))
            .animation(.default)
        
        Button("update") { update.toggle() }
        
    }
}
```

---

update:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var updateEdge: Edge = Edge.top
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(uiImage: slideStore.images[activeImageIndex])
            .resizable()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .scaledToFill()
            .transition(.move(edge: updateEdge ))
            .animation(.default)
        
        Button("updateEdge") { updateEdge = Edge.leading }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonder if I needed for options .leading, .trailing, .top, and .bottom?

Comment: in my answer as well